# Databricks - How can I copy driver logs to my machine?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I can see logs using %sh command on databricks driver node. 
How can I copy them on my windows machine for analysis?

%sh
cd eventlogs/4246832951093966440
gunzip eventlog-2019-07-22--14-00.gz
ls -l
head -1 eventlog-2019-07-22--14-00
Version":"2.4.0","Timestamp":1563801898572,"Rollover Number":0,"SparkContext Id":4246832951093966440}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get files using
`databricks fs cp`

for more options see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli) and `databricks fs -h`

(Alternatively you could also export to log analytics workspace in order to centralize logs inside native Azure tooling)