# Over-writing log4j properties to filter logs in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, databricks

I am running my jobs on Databricks clusters. For every job run, spark driver logs are generated which consists of stdout, sterr and log4j files. I've also used the same log4j library in my code for logging & hence my logs are printed as a part of driver log4j log files.
[image]

The problem is majority of driver log4j files contains logs generated by databricks or spark and it becomes really difficult to search for my project related logs. I did add a prefix to my logs to make my search a bit easier but still its not convenient enough.

Log4j file looks something like this -

```
19/12/03 15:45:30 INFO ScalaDriverWrapper: setupRepl:ReplId-54fb1-f8f43-0a75c-a: finished to load
19/12/03 15:45:30 WARN ScalaDriverLocal: User entity information is incomplete, missing userId,user.
19/12/03 15:45:30 INFO ProgressReporter$: Added result fetcher for 6123522818505864650_7748591541637124368_job-186-run-1-action-185
19/12/03 15:45:35 INFO MY_LOGS: Entry Point Params : 
19/12/03 15:45:35 INFO MY_LOGS: Methods 1 begins
19/12/03 15:45:35 INFO MY_LOGS: Applying some pre-checks
19/12/03 15:45:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at webConfig.scala:27) with 1 output partitions
19/12/03 15:45:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at webConfig.scala:27)
19/12/03 15:45:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/12/03 15:45:35 INFO MY_LOGS: Applying some post-checks
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                .
```

I need to filter the driver logs from the standard log4j files created on every job run on Databricks such that I am able to create a new file containing only those logs that are logged using my code and then write them in a new file on some dbfs location. I have appended a unique string to identify these logs (MY_LOGS) but I can't seem to find a way to (may be) over-write existing log4j properties used by databricks clusters.

So far I've tried writing a simple test batch script and attaching it in init scripts as suggested [here](https://kb.databricks.com/clusters/overwrite-log4j-logs.html). 
[image]
But it is not working and the cluster fails to start during initialization itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for exactly the same thing. This would be the ideal case. But, as of now, I have one workaround that can help you solve part of your problem.

1. Move the driver logs to some location using databricks-cli [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148116/databricks-how-can-i-copy-driver-logs-to-my-machine/57287416#57287416).
2. Use a python script with regex to get logs of your interest.

At the same time, I agree with your approach and believe there should be a better way to accomplish this.